# Perché si dice “che pizza” per esprimere noia?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Vorrei sapere l’origine dell’espressione “che pizza” per esprimere noia.

Ho trovato in rete un sacco di [supposizioni](https://www.lettera43.it/it/comefare/curiosita/2017/07/12/perche-si-dice-che-pizza/8208/) e [spiegazioni](https://www.garysassano.it/che-cavolo-che-pizza/) ma nessuna che abbia un fondamento o provenga da fonti attendibili.

Qui di seguito le supposizioni:

> In particolare sono tre le possibili interpretazioni:
>
> 1. per pizza non
>    si intende la pietanza vera e propria, ma la custodia metallica che
>    contiene la pellicola cinematografica, chiamata anch'essa per
>    l'appunto “pizza”, per cui probabilmente questa locuzione deriva da un
>    film lungo e noioso.
> 2. La pizza, intesa come pietanza, è di forma
>    piatta, pertanto questo modo di dire potrebbe aver avuto origine per
>    analogia pizza = piattume = noia.
> 3. L'ultima via interpretativa è
>    sempre legata alla pizza intesa come pietanza, a differenza della
>    precedente non si riferisce alla forma ma ai tempi lunghi di
>    levitazione della pasta che in media richiede un giorno intero.

Qui quella considerata spiegazione:

> Tante volte si dice “che pizza!“, per dire “che noia!”, che roba lunga
> e senza fine. Ecco, ma cosa ha a che fare ciò con le pizze, quelle
> così buone che si possono mangiare? Soltanto un contenitore.
> Un tempo
> infatti, al posto delle scatole in cartone, le pizze venivano
> trasportate dentro dei contenitori di metallo che le conservavano
> calde. Le bobine cinematografiche erano conservate dentro dei
> contenitori di metallo affini, simili esternamente a quelli con cui si
> trasportavano calde le pizze. 
> La cosa è incominciata dicendo di un
> film “che pizza!“, cioè vale soltanto sì e no la pellicola con cui è
> stato fatto, ma per il resto non vale niente. Quando finisce questo
> film? Quando finisce questo filmato? Quando finisce questa bobina?
> Ecco da dove deriva il modo di dire “che pizza!“

Infine, [questa ulteriore spiegazione](http://www.storiedipersone.com/wordpress/ma-che-pizza-ora-ho-capito-il-perche/) viene considerata più autorevole:

> Continuando la mia ricerca, ho trovato una versione più autorevole
> proveniente dall’Accademia Pizzaioli di Gruaro, in provincia di
> Venezia. Secondo loro questo detto popolare deriva dal fatto che la
> pizza a volte risulta difficile da digerire, causando gonfiore e molta
> sete. Le cause possono essere imputate ad una lievitazione troppo
> breve o all’impiego di ingredienti di scarsa qualità. Ecco spiegato il
> perché.

Sarebbe preferibile che fosse l’Accademia della Crusca...

Comment: Potresti aggiungere qualcuna di queste spiegazioni?

Comment: Spiegazioni aggiunte.

Comment: Mah, a me verrebbe da dire che è come "che cavolo", "acciderba" o "porca miseria", un eufemismo che rende accettabile quella che in realtà sarebbe una parolaccia.

Comment: Intanto ecco un principio d'analisi: https://www.google.it/search?lr=lang_it&hl=it&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q="Che+pizza"&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min:1+gen+1945,cd_max:31+dic+1965&num=30 Google books attesta il "Che pizza" per lè proms volte negli anni '50. (Non riesco a vedere altro di quel riferimento della frase di Ciano, sarebbe interessante saperne di più)

Comment: A me viene in mente questa interpretazione: essendo la pizza un cibo molto diffuso, una scelta sicura, frequente, "ovvia", qualcosa di noioso o ripetitivo viene associato alla pizza

Comment: Dal vocabolario Treccani, secondo significato della parola pizza:
"2. a. estens. Ciò che risulta di un oggetto in seguito a schiacciamento: si è seduto sul cappello e l’ha fatto diventare una pizza.
b. fig. Persona o cosa terribilmente noiosa, insopportabile".
Potrebbe avere a che fare con lo schiacciamento, con la sensazione di essere schiacciati da qualcosa?

Comment: Visto che la domanda è tornata all'attenzione, dico il mio parere: la spiegazione giusta è quella cinematografica. Un film è una pizza se è noioso: nel gergo del cinematografo, la pizza è la scatola rotonda che contiene la bobina; il film è una pizza se consiste solo della pellicola, senza alcun valore aggiunto.

Comment: Io appoggio la teoria dell'impiparsi

Answer (score 2):

Che io sappia *che pizza* è semplicemente un eufemismo per *che palle* che suona simile, così come *che cavolo*, *mavaffancuore*, *porco zio*, e così via. Si tratta di una forma di censura la cui ambiguità aiuta a conservare l'effetto della parolaccia ma riducendo il rischio di ricevere uno scappellotto dalla mamma. :)

Si tratta di un meccanismo presente anche in altre lingue, per esempio in inglese si dice *shoot!*, *dang it* o *I'm freaking hungry*, o in ceco *do prčic* ("vai a Prcic" simile a "vai a quel paese").

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, ma le risposte veramente utili sono quelle suffragate da qualche fonte. Probabilmente quasi tutti i frequentatori di questo sito hanno in testa un loro “che io sappia”, come vedi anche nei commenti e nel testo stesso della domanda, mentre ancora nessuno – me compreso – ha trovato riferimenti concreti in dizionari, repertori di modi di dire e così via.

Answer (score -1):

Tendo a sostenere la tesi dell'eufemismo; ma non di "palle" bensì di "pippa", ovvero masturbazione maschile, termine che dà luogo anche al verbo "impipparsi" (me ne impippo) che ha la stessa valenza di "fregarsi" (me ne frego). Del resto un equivalente di "che pizza!" è "che sega!". Anche questa mia è comunque solo una supposizione non corroborata da alcuna fonte.
Secondo la Treccani, il termine "pippa" con questo significato è attestato a partire dal 1965. Si potrebbe vedere se la locuzione "che pizza" si riscontri già prima del '65, nel qual caso la mia supposizione sarebbe da scartare.

Comment: Occhio, che non è “impipparsi”, ma “impiparsi”: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiparsi

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo intervento. Tieni conto, però, che, come si è detto in un commento alla risposta precedente, le risposte veramente utili sono quelle suffragate da qualche fonte.